# Cancelling thread that is stuck on epoll_wait

Tags: c++, pthreads, epoll

I'm doing some event handling with C++ and pthreads. I have a main thread that reads from event queue I defined, and a worker thread that fills the event queue. The queue is of course thread safe.

The worker thread have a list of file descriptors and create an epoll system call to get events on those file descriptors. It uses epoll_wait to wait for events on the fd's.

Now the problem. Assuming I want to terminate my application cleanly, how can I cancel the worker thread properly? `epoll_wait` is not one of the cancellation points of [pthread(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) so it cannot react properly on `pthread_cancel`.

The worker thread main() looks like this

```
while(m_WorkerRunning) {
    epoll_wait(m_EpollDescriptor, events, MAXEVENTS, -1);
    //handle events and insert to queue
}
```

The `m_WorkerRunning` is set to `true` when the thread starts and it looks like I **can** interrupt the thread by settings `m_WorkerRunning` to false from the main thread. The problem is that `epoll_wait` theoretically can wait forever.

Other solution I though about is: instead of waiting forever (-1) I can wait for example X time slots, then handle properly no-events case and if `m_WorkerRunning == false` then exit the loop and terminate the worker thread cleanly. The main thread then sets `m_WorkerRunning` to false, and sleeps X. However I'm not sure about the performance of such epoll_wait and also not sure what would be the correct X? 500ms? 1s? 10s?

I'd like to hear some experienced advises!

More relevant information: the fd's I'm waiting events on, are devices in `/dev/input` so technically I'm doing some sort of input subsystem. The targeted OS is Linux (latest kernel) on ARM architecture.

Thanks!

Comment: It's waiting on events, right?  So, signal one!  Set some atomic 'Stop' boolean that is checked after every epoll_wait and, well, signal something- add an fd you can signal.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not sure I understand you. You suggest to add some dummy fd that I can push events to from the main thread? And then in worked to check if the event came from that dummy fd, terminate the thread?

Comment: I found this http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html Looks like it can be used as dummy fd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could send the thread a signal which would interupt the blocking call to `epoll_wait()`. If doing so modify your code like this:

```
while(m_WorkerRunning) 
{
  int result = epoll_wait(m_EpollDescriptor, events, MAXEVENTS, -1);
  if (-1 == result)
  {
    if (EINTR == errno)
    {
      /* Handle shutdown request here. */ 
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      /* Error handling goes here. */
    }
  }

  /* Handle events and insert to queue. */
}
```

---

A way to add a signal handler:

```
#include <signal.h>

/* A generic signal handler doing nothing */
void signal_handler(int sig)
{
  sig = sig; /* Cheat compiler to not give a warning about an unused variable. */
}

/* Wrapper to set a signal handler */
int signal_handler_set(int sig, void (*sa_handler)(int))
{
  struct sigaction sa = {0};
  sa.sa_handler = sa_handler;
  return sigaction(sig, &sa, NULL);
}
```

To set this handler for the signal `SIGUSR1` do:

```
if (-1 == signal_handler_set(SIGUSR1, signal_handler))
{
  perror("signal_handler_set() failed");
}
```

To send a signal `SIGUSR1` from another process:

```
if (-1 == kill(<target process' pid>, SIGUSR1))
{
  perror("kill() failed");
}
```

To have a process send a signal to itself:

```
if (-1 == raise(SIGUSR1))
{
  perror("raise() failed");
}
```

Comment: Could you be kind and also add an example of how to send this signal? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @skwee: Use the `kill()` (see `man 2 kill`) command to send a signal to a process. Also you might need to add a signal handler (doing nothing) to the receiving process for the signal you are going to send, as the default behaviour on receiving that signal could be to simply end the whole process. I'd also recommend to read `man 7 signal` and `man sigaction`. Also avoid using the function `signal()` as it's behaviour differs from implementation to implementation . On the command line there is the equvivalent command `kill` (see `man kill`) available. If nothing helps just add another question.

Comment: @skwee: Please see my updated answer for some example snippets.

Comment: @alk Is it the same if I install the interrupt handler as SIG_IGN, rather than create an explicit empty handler?

Comment: @RobinHsu: If the signal is ignored it is not received. If the signal is not received the blocking function will not be interupted. So no, ignoring a signal is not the same as receiving it, doing nothing.

Answer (score 12):

alk's answer above is *almost* correct. The difference, however, is very dangerous.

If you are going to send a signal in order to wake up `epoll_wait`, **never** use epoll_wait. You must use `epoll_pwait`, or you might run into a race with your epoll never waking up.

Signals arrive asynchronously. If your `SIGUSR1` arrives after you've checked your shutdown procedure, but before your loop returns to the `epoll_wait`, then the signal will not interrupt the wait (as there is none), but neither will the program exit.

This might be very likely or extremely unlikely, depending on how long the loop takes in relation to how much time is spent in the wait, but it is a bug one way or the other.

Another problem with alk's answer is that it does not check *why* the wait was interrupted. It might be any number of reasons, some unrelated to your exit.

For more information, see the man page for [`pselect`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pselect). `epoll_pwait` works in a similar way.

Also, never send signals to threads using `kill`. Use [`pthread_kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) instead. `kill`'s behavior when sending signals is, at best, undefined. There is no guarantee that the correct thread will receive it, which might cause an unrelated system call to be interrupted, or nothing at all to happen.